# Codeigniter task scheduling

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am not very much sure if my title question is correct, however i am facing sever error of multiple loops within foreach, despite of having only one item in array. I am pasting my code here;

**Display** (Controller)

```
$table_data = array(
                'table_data' => $this->display_model->get_table_data($table_name),
                'edit_table_data'=>$this->display_model->get_table_data($table_name,$row_id) 
            );

$form_name='edit_'.$table_name;

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view($form_name,$table_data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

You can see **tabe_data** and **edit_table_data** is calling same function with different parameter. 
Here i doubt on the time scheduling between these two function calls (which honestly i am wrong because codeigniter manages function calls)

**Display_model** (Model)

```
public function get_table_data($table_name,$row_id=null)
{
    $return = "";

    if ($row_id != null) 
    {
        switch ($table_name) {

            case 'user':

                //$return = $this->db->where($table_name."_id",$row_id)->get($table_name)->result();
                $return = $this->db->select($table_name.'.*,country.country_name')
                ->join('country','country.country_id=user.user_country_id','left')
                ->where($table_name.'_id',$row_id)
                ->get($table_name)->result();
                break;

            case 'user_document':

                //$return = $this->db->where($table_name."_id",$row_id)->get($table_name)->result();
                $return = $this->db->select($table_name.'.*,document.document_name')
                ->join('document','document.document_id=use_document.document_id','left')
                ->where($table_name.'_id',$row_id)
                ->get($table_name)->result();
                break;

            default:

                $return = $this->db->where($table_name."_id",$row_id)->get($table_name)->result();

                break;
        }

    if($return != null)
    {
        return $return;
    }
    else
    {
        return "no_data";
    }
}
```

Here is my view where i am getting error

```
                <?php foreach ($edit_table_data as $etd_row) {?>
                <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/edit_row/user_type/'.$etd_row->user_type_id)?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">User Type Name</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_type_name" value="<?php echo $etd_row->user_type_name?>"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Edit changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
                <?php } ?>
```

on the foreach loop line, i am given error

[image: Invalid argument supplied for foreach]

Thanks in advance for your comments

**Error**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/edit_user_type.php

Line Number: 18

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\gmf\application\views\edit_user_type.php
Line: 18
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\gmf\application\controllers\Display.php
Line: 170
Function: view

File: C:\wamp\www\gmf\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: get_table_data can return a string (no_data) which is an invalid argument for foreach. If this is the case, make it return an empty array instead of a string.

Comment: check for empty like this in your view  `if (! empty($edit_table_data)){ foreach($edit_table_data as $etd_row){}}`

Comment: Actually $edit_table_data is an array and it is not null, did check this in model and view, both places

Answer (score 0):

You'd get this error if `$edit_table_data` is not an array -- in this case probably a string.

My CI knowledge is a bit rusty, but I guess something along these lines may help you out:

```
$query = $this->db->select($table_name.'.*,country.country_name')
->join('country','country.country_id=user.user_country_id','left')
->where($table_name.'_id',$row_id)
->get($table_name);

if ($query->num_rows() === 0){
    return []; // Make sure we're always returning an array.
    // I'd rather handle this stuff in the view...
    // Probably some kind of message that shows:
    // that there are not results when $edit_table_data is not an array, otherwise loop.

}

return $query->result();
```

Or you could do something along these lines:

```
<?php
if (!is_array($edit_table_data)) {
    echo 'No results here.';
} else {
    foreach ($edit_table_data as $etd_row) { ?>
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal"
              action="<?php echo site_url('admin/edit_row/user_type/' . $etd_row->user_type_id) ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">User Type Name</label>

                <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_type_name"
                                             value="<?php echo $etd_row->user_type_name ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Edit changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have updated my question and added error, can you please check. Problem is that the array is not empty and it is an array because the edit for is being populated, meaning that foreach loop is run. However, it runs on an on without being stopped.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a reason to call `get_table_data` twice, once with and once without `$row_id`, because you never use `$table_data['$table_data']` in the view. In the interests of getting something that works that first call should be eliminated. The revised controller looks like this.

```
$table_data['edit_table_data'] = $this->display_model->get_table_data($table_name,$row_id) ;

$form_name='edit_'.$table_name;

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view($form_name,$table_data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

The model code in the question is missing a curly brace `}` to close this statement.

```
if ($row_id != null) 
{
```

So it is a little hard to tell exactly what you want to happen if `$row_id` is not provided. Without further information, my opinion is that `get_table_data` should not give the second argument a default value. In other words, the function should be defined without a default value for `$row_id - like this.

```
public function get_table_data($table_name, $row_id)
```

Without a default value for `$row_id a fatal error occurs if no value is provided. So the controller will need to make sure a value is provided. 
Likewise, the controller should always check the return of the model is appropriate, or the model should always return something that the view can use.

`get_table_data()` contains a lot of repeated code - `where($table_name.'_id', $row_id)` and `get($table_name)->result()` appear three times each. By rearranging the logic, the repeating lines can be eliminated to make the function much more concise. Consider this version.

```
public function get_table_data($table_name, $row_id)
{
    if($table_name === 'user')
    {
        $this->db
            ->select($table_name.'.*, country.country_name')
            ->join('country', 'country.country_id = user.user_country_id', 'left');
    }
    elseif($table_name === 'user_document')
    {
        $this->db
            ->select($table_name.'.* ,document.document_name')
            ->join('document', 'document.document_id = use_document.document_id', 'left');
    }

    return $this->db
            ->where($table_name."_id", $row_id)
            ->get($table_name)
            ->row();
}
```

The above returns data from any `$table_name` where `$table_name."_id" == $row_id`. Specific "select" and "join" clauses are added in the case of 'user' or 'user_document' tables.

Because you seem to be interested in only one row you should call `row()` instead of `result()`.

It's important to know that `db->row()` will return NULL if no records are found. That fact can be used to test the model return and react appropriately. In this case, we do the check in the view. Because there is only one row. no `foreach` is needed.

```
<?php if(isset($edit_table_data)) { ?>
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/edit_row/user_type/'.$edit_table_data->user_type_id) ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">User Type Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_type_name" value="<?php echo $edit_table_data->user_type_name ?>"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Edit changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
}
else { ?> <div>No Data Available</div> <?php } ?>
```